# Xcode 11 Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, xcode11

This question has been asked before, but my issue is specifically with Xcode 11 and `UISceneConfiguration`. Before Xcode 11, when you deleted a storyboard (`Main.storyboard`) from your target, then added a new one (`AnotherStoryboard.storyboard`), you would have to update `Targets > General > Deployment Info > Main Interface` to use your newly added storyboard. In Xcode 11, this is not sufficient and the app will throw an exception

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle
```

The problem I found was that in `Info.plist`, there is now a new key titled `UIApplicationSceneManifest` that has a nested `UISceneStoryboardFile` in it that is being updated when you change the Main Interface within the target. However, there is still a `UIMainStoryboardFile` key at the top level of `Info.plist` that is holding the title of the old "Main" storyboard. Long story short, if you delete `UIMainStoryboardFile`, the app will run fine.

My question: Is this a bug in Xcode 11 or is there something else I'm missing that would prevent this? I didn't really find anything useful while I was trying to debug it and ended up figuring it out on my own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `info.plist` `Main` file is set in `Scene Configuration`, So it always find that file and throw an exception. You can set your default `ViewController` programatically. In your `info.plist` set `Scene Configuration` to `Default configuration` and Select none into `Targets` > `General` > `Deployment Info` > `Main Interface`.

Your `sceneWillConnectTo` be like

```
  window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
  window!.windowScene = windowScene
  window!.rootViewController = //your homeVC
  window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your info.plist you have to set this property
Application Scene Manifest -> Scene Configuration -> Application Session Role -> Item 0 -> Storyboard Name

[Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLDS0.png)

Comment: if duplicate targets are added in project then newly created infolist should be updated by respective storyboard name.As mentioned above.